# Memory leak in WebTestCase or in Symfony2-Kernel - how to report to the gurus?

Tags: memory-leaks, symfony

I think I have found a memory-leak in the WebTestCase class or in the Kernel itself. My questions at the end.

To reproduce, I make a new empty WebTestCase that does $max asserts (in my tests, $max ranges from 1 to 100.000) without instancing any kernel.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
class DemoTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testHello(  )
    {
        $max = 100000;
        for( $i = 0; $i < 1; $i++ )
        {
            $this->assertTrue( true );
        }
    }
}
```

With $max=1

```
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.75Mb
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

With $max=100000

```
Time: 1 second, Memory: 5.75Mb
OK (1 test, 100000 assertions)
```

As expected, either running 1 time or 100.000 times, I consume the same memory.

Now I try the loop creating any arbitrary class, working with it and destroying it. I choose DOMDocument the same way I could have chosen any other class.

```
    public function testHello(  )
    {
        $max = 100000;
        for( $i = 0; $i < $max; $i++ )
        {
            $dummy = new \DOMDocument();
            $dummy->loadHTML( '<html><head><title>dummy</title></head><body>dummy</body></html>' );
            unset( $dummy );
            $this->assertTrue( true );
        }
    }
```

With $max=1

```
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.75Mb
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

With $max=100000

```
Time: 2 seconds, Memory: 5.75Mb
OK (1 test, 100000 assertions)
```

Again, regardless if I execute it 1 time or 100.000, I consume the same memory.

But... Now I create and destroy kernels within the loop. I NEITHER DO the ->boot() nor the ->shutdown(), just obtain the new kernel objects that, without even being booted, are then unreferenced, ans so they should die freeing all their resources.

```
    public function testHello(  )
    {
        $max = 10000;
        for( $i = 0; $i < $max; $i++ )
        {
            $dummy = static::createKernel();
            unset( $dummy );
            $this->assertTrue( true );
        }
    }
```

With $max=1

```
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.25Mb
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

With $max=100000

```
Time: 9 seconds, Memory: 165.50Mb
OK (1 test, 100000 assertions)
```

It is logical that it raises from 5.75 to 6.25, it might be the size of the kernel's resources. Half mega. But what is incorrect it is the fact of taht by creating 100.000 kernels without any operations on them, we tend to consume 165 megas. Somebody is freeing bad the resources that it allocated.

*My questions:*

- Is this a leak? Or it is the expected behaviour which, for any extrange reason I don't get why should this work as it does?
- I use 2.0.10. If it is a leak, how can I know if this is corrected in a later version?
- If it has not been corrected, which is the easiest way to report it to the core-team?

Thanks!
Xavi.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony2 code is hosted on github.com and issues must declared on this site https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues

I encounter this kind of issue with heavy web testcases too, and it's not fixed in 2.0.x versions. I can't ensure you it's a memory leak or normal behaviour...

- Google Groups for developers : http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-devs?pli=1
- Google Groups for users : http://groups.google.com/group/symfony2?pli=1
- Symfony2 forum : http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewforum.php?f=23

I advise you the Google Groups mailing list, and then GitHub issues.

Comment: Before submitting it as a bug, is there any kind of "developers mailing list" to discuss it and distinguish if its a bug or feature? Thanks.